# Force contribution of image atom using periodic boundary conditions

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

This is maybe a stupid question but lead to a discussion between me an my colleagues. If we use periodic boundary conditions and an atom has itself as neighbor do we need special care of this contribution to the Force?

In all cases the Energy depends on the distance $r_{ij}$ between two atoms $i$ and $j$. In case of the periodic image the distance will be the position of the image translated by the Lattice vector and thus just $L$. Since the movement of the atom and its image is correlated the distance between them will never change and thus the derivative $\partial r_{ij}/\partial x_i$ vanishes and this also leads to zero Force. However, I think there is a mistake in our assumption. I feel uncomfortable to just setting this Force to zero. The Force also enters the virial and thus the pressure and stress. If the contribution would be zero there would be no stress in a single atom system with PBCs.

I just hope that some one can clear my thoughts on this matter.

Comment: The force of an image atom on the original is *not* zero - it is a different atom. Think about a physical crystal, an atom in one cell is different from one in another cell even if they are related by a translation which is a lattice vector. Whether to have such a small cell that such forces are significant is another matter all together and depends upon what you are modelling. I suspect if the correlated motions are worrying you then you need a bigger simulation cell, one of sufficient size that the term you are worrying about are negligible.

Comment: To put it another way if you want one atom to move in one way and another translationally symmetry related one to move in a different one, then your cell is too small; symmetry constraints due to PBC make such a calculation impossible.

Comment: Might want to consider moving this post to matter modeling SE.

Comment: Thank you @IanBush I also think that the image atom should be treated as a new independent atom, but I'm still a bit struggling with it mathematically. My colleagues made the valid point that the movement will always be correlated. If I account for this in the distance $\vec{r}_{ij}=\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_i-n\vec{L}$ then the gradient of this distance w.r.t. coordinate change vanishes. Probably one should just not account for the correlated movement, but I wish I had a more clear mathematical proof Buck Thorn How can I move the post?